# IPP Driver is missing in Windows 10 (needed to connect to CUPS)

Tags: windows, printing, cups

I have a HP Color Laserjet Pro 454dn printer connected to **CUPS**, but some of my **Windows 10 computers can't print Duplex** to it. Android and IOS devices have no problem printing duplex. I did notice that the driver on the working Windows 10 computer is a "Microsoft IPP driver". I cannot find this driver on the other computers. Does anyone know how to install this? I have turned the "Internet Printing Client" on, but this does not help. Also, I have tried the universal and device specific drivers from HP both with post script and PCL, some print only greyscale and others don't print duplex.

Android and iOS can print without drivers. I have looked into driverless printing for Windows, have made no progress. This would be my favourite solution.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Printer drivers are critical to the printing model under Windows.  I don't think you can print without one.  If Microsoft doesn't provide an appropriate one and HP doesn't either, you may be stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How come some of the Computers have the Driver and others don't? Where can I download the Microsoft IPP driver?

Comment: If I knew that, I would have left an answer instead of a comment.  I only said something so you wouldn't be surprised when no answer was forthcoming.  There might be better places to ask too.

Answer (score 0):

The IPP Driver is built into Windows 10.  You might want to look at adding SAMBA to your CUPS implementation.  Especially for older Windows and Android clients wanting to see your printer.

Click the 'The Printer that I want isn't listed'.

Then the radio button of "Select a shared printer by name".

Then put the printer network name in the window using this format:
http://hostname-or-ip-of-your-pi:631/printers/Printer_Name

Windows will now find the printer and ask for a print driver for it.

This link tells you all you ever wanted to know about CUPS printing but assumes your using Ubuntu to make a network printer:  http://www.auxnet.org/index.php/the-news/214-installing-an-ipp-printer-in-windows-10

Comment: Do you have more information when saying "the IPP Driver is built into Windows 10"? I am sure I have a Windows 10 20H2 version but there is no IPP Driver installed